# Drag-Drop event with Constraint Layout

Tags: java, android

We are making a project.Were we need to intefrate drag-n-drop, but we are using constraint layouts.I think to convert it to java for creating dynamically drag-drop but how can i handle those dragdrop events and convert those constraint layouts ?

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop of view onto other views and view groups have been supported since Android API level 14 and it does n't depend on Layout type. Views have methods called `startDrag()` and `OnDragListener()` to handle this action. To use dragging a view you register an `OnTouchListener` or a `LongClickListener` on the view which can be dragged like so:

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(
                view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
});
```

To specify the picture used for the drag operation you can use `DragShadowBuilder`.

The views which can be drop targets should implement `OnDragListener` like below:

```
constraintLayout2.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_STARTED ");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED ");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_EXITED ");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                owner.removeView(view);
                ConstraintLayout container = (ConstraintLayout) v;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Log.d(TAG, "onDrag: ACTION_DRAG_ENDED ");
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

In `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP` case you could define what happens when the user drops the drag-able item. As you can see in this case drag a view from a `ViewGroup` which can be a `Layout` and drop it in a `ConstraintLayout` that it's a `ViewGroup` as well.